# Delphi: How to check for valid login from SQLite database using App tethering?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, client-server, delphi-xe8

I've Client And Server Apps.

In a Client Side I've Authorization. 
In a Server Side I've SQLite database.

In a Client Side Using: App tethering(TTetheringAppProfile and TTetheringManager), 2 Edits and 2 Buttons(Connect Button and Login Button)...

In a Server Side Using: App tethering(TTetheringAppProfile and TTetheringManager), SQLite database, TFDConnection, TFDQuery...

**Client Side using APP TETHERING sending data to Server Database to check. IF Username And Password Correct it should show me MessageBox('Success!!!'). Otherwise MessageBox('Be sure username and password is correct');**

Client Side Code:

```
    procedure TfAuth.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles[0],'Login',tLogin.Text);
  tAProfile.SendString(tManager.RemoteProfiles[0],'Password',tPassword.Text);
end;
```

Server Side Code:

```
procedure TfServerPage.tAProfileResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject;
  const AResource: TRemoteResource);
  var aLogin, aPassword:TStringList;
begin
  aLogin:=TStringList.Create;
  aPassword:=TStringList.Create;


  if AResource.Hint = 'Login' then
    begin
      aLogin.Text:=AResource.Value.AsString;
    end
  else if AResource.Hint = 'Password' then
    begin
     aPassword.Text:=AResource.Value.AsString;
    end;
  rQuery.Close;
  rQuery.Close;
  rQuery.SQL.Clear;
  rQuery.SQL.Add('select * from authoriation where name='+QuotedStr(aLogin.Text)+'and password='+QuotedStr(aPassword.Text));
  rQuery.Open;
   if rQuery.RecordCount = 0 then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Be sure user name and password is correct');
      end
   else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Success!!!');
      end
end;
```

[image: Server And Client Image...]

Comment: Which version are you using. XE or XE8?

Comment: Delphi XE8 . Multi-device application.

Comment: So best to remove the misleading XE text and tags

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the database on Server and capture the result; Correct connection or error.

Using the same method to send parameters to server, you can send the result of the operation to the client, with True/False, 0/1 or something else. Also you can [use Shared resources](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Sharing_Data_with_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering) to do the same operation/comunication.

You can do something like this:

1. In the Server (inside `TtetheringAppProfile`) you can define a Shared Resource named **SharedRes1**, whith:

> ```
>  IsPublic=True;
>  Kind=Shared;
>  Name=SharedRes1;
>  ResType=Data;
> ```

2. In the Client you can suscribe to this Resource with:

> ```
> var   
>   pInfo:TTetheringProfileInfo;   
>   rRes:TRemoteResource; 
> begin   
>   pInfo := ttManager.RemoteProfiles[0];   
>   rRes := ttaProfile.GetRemoteResourceValue(pInfo, 'SharedRes1');
>   ttaProfile.SubscribeToRemoteItem(pInfo, rRes);
> ```

3. Now, you can use this resource to send information from server to the client, assigning data to this resource:

> ```
> ttaProfile.Resources.FindByName('SharedRes1').Value := 
>   FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', Now)
> ```

Using this system you can exchange different information between the two programs.

NOTE: I added quotes to the code because without it, the code don't format correctly.

Comment: Bro, can you give me example...?

Comment: I have added some sample code and explanations to my anterior  message.